# spring oauth2 only return the access_token and not the refresh_token

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

i started a new project with boot and oauth2. I set client_credentials as grant_type with refresh_token but a got only the access_token and not the refresh.

Here my clientDetailsServiceConfigurer:

```
.withClient("XXXXX")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
            .authorities(ROLE_PRODUCER)
            .scopes(SCOPE_WRITE)
            .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
            .secret("WSEWEWEWEW")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200);
```

the response of the server:

```
{"access_token":"XXXX","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":6901,"scope":"write"}
```

Comment: Hello are you able get refresh_token ?

Comment: no, not possible and you?

Comment: I have been trying to have integration for zapier. Everythings looks fine actually even i can get refresh_token with, grand_type=password but i am not sure zapier can't refresh token. So i always get 401 after a while.